# Detecting and extracting Wingdings/Webdings/Symbol character

Tags: regex, perl

```
    ................
    ................
    open(my $FILE, "<", "$dfn");
    binmode($FILE);
    @lines = <$FILE>;
    close($FILE);
    $data = join ('', @lines);

    foreach (0 .. $#lines) {
           if ($lines[$_] =~ m#Wingdings.*?>(.*?)<.*>#i) {
                $Wingdings_text_fetch = $1;
                if(!$Wingdings_text_fetch){
                      if ($lines[$_] =~ m#Wingdings.*>(.*)<#i){
                            $Wingdings_text_fetch = $1;
                      }
            }
          elsif ($lines[$_] =~ m#Webdings.*?>(.*?)<.*>#i) {
                $Webdings_font_text_fetch = $1;
                if(!$Webdings_font_text_fetch){
                     if ($lines[$_] =~ m#Webdings.*>(.*)<#i){
                            $Webdings_font_text_fetch = $1;
                      }
         }
          elsif ($lines[$_] =~ m#Symbol.*?>(.*?)<.*>#i) {
                $Symbol_font_text_fetch = $1;
                if(!$Symbol_font_text_fetch){
                     if ($lines[$_] =~ m#Symbol.*>(.*)<#i){
                            $Symbol_font_text_fetch = $1;
                     }
         }
      #....................some more task...............#
    }
```

The above works fine on the below cases.

Wingdings:

```
<p class=MsoNormal><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span
style='font-size:13.0pt;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial;color:#000099'><a
href="#terug"><span style='font-family:Wingdings;mso-ascii-font-family:Arial;
mso-hansi-font-family:Arial;mso-char-type:symbol;mso-symbol-font-family:Wingdings'><span
style='mso-char-type:symbol;mso-symbol-font-family:Wingdings'>Ç</span></span></a></span></b><span
style='font-size:13.0pt;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Symbol:

```
<p class=MsoListParagraph style='margin-top:1.0pt;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:
1.0pt;margin-left:1.0cm;text-indent:-14.15pt'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;
font-family:Symbol;color:black'>·</span><span style='font-size:7.0pt;
color:black'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>some text</span></p>
```

but it fails on the below cases (mostly due to the multiline).

```
<p class=MsoListParagraph style='margin-top:1.0pt;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:
1.0pt;margin-left:1.0cm;mso-add-space:auto;text-indent:-14.15pt;mso-list:l5 level1 lfo35'><![if !supportLists]><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:Symbol;mso-fareast-font-family:Symbol;
mso-bidi-font-family:Symbol;color:black;mso-ansi-language:NL-BE'><span
style='mso-list:Ignore'>·<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
color:black;mso-ansi-language:NL-BE'>some text here.<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Any idea on what should be the regex to include the last case also? Since I'm checking line by line in script, so I'm unable to fit multi line regex there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise against using a regex for parsing HTML.

Instead use an actual html parser like [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) or my new personal favorite [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM).  There's even a nice 8 minute video on how to use the latter available at [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

Comment: I thought I was Chuck Norris.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
font-family:(Wingdings|Webdings|Symbol).+?>([^<>]+)#is
```

For handling multiline, use the `s` modifier so `.` will match newlines.

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: nice diagram - is that generated?